# Mysql 5.6.33 Transaction react differently on my machine and server?

Tags: mysql, transactions, plesk, mysql-connector

I have 2 table in my database. 1 is e and 2nd is eitem.

Through code I start a transaction in c#. I change the e.type to 8 in first table and then I run  a command.

```
update eitem
    set ....
    Where eitem = 2
```

and commit through c# code.

1. On my Computer it's worked fine. In my 2nd query I write 2 in condition which is actually 8 (if transaction succeed but I didn't commit it yet)
2. On server 2nd command didn't do anything because it's simply can't find the row with type 2. I still didn't commit it yet but why it can't find the row.

In both case the things are very confusing. I am in middle or transaction. Should I write condition with old information or new information. I am no MySQL expert and I am not sure which one is correct condition. I am using 5.6.33 on my pc come from Oracle. and Server is using MySQL which come with plesk.

Someone please help me with this. I have no idea why things are run differently on my machine and server.

First table

```
Id, eitem

1    2
```

My first query change eitem from to 8. The confusion is now for 2nd query what thing I should put in condition, 2 or 8. eitem was 2 before my transaction. and eitem is now 8 during my tranasaction.

on my computer it's work when I pass 2. So on my pc the value is before the session and it's working if i use them in WHERE.

on server it's not working because mysql react as like it's 8 but it's not committed yet.

Comment: At least for me it's hard to follow what's happening where and what the relationship between local and server machine is. Could you be more specific? E.g. add some sample data before the update, all sql queries you use (including a marker where you start and commit the transaction), and the result afterwards. For both servers. There will probably be follow up questions (e.g. about your table definition/engine type, potential triggers, connection, maybe your c# code) to localize potential reasons, and you could add these already, but as a 1st step I'd like to understand the problem itself.

Comment: @Solarflare Please check my question, I add some more details.

Comment: Sorry, it is still unclear what you are doing and what you are getting. You e.g. say "on my computer it's work", then the next sentence is "on my computer it's not working". Instead of describing in words what you did, it is *much* more precise if you add the 2 queries (or 4 if they are not identical on your two servers), where (on what server/connection/transaction) you execute them, as well as the initial values and the final values on your two servers (and maybe the intermediate values after the first query).

Comment: @Solarflare My apologies, on 2nd line I means on sever.

Comment: That was not my main problem. I really(!!!!) don't understand what you did, so I can't even tell you the next step to look at. You seem to have some problem with transactions. There are about 20+ reasons for that. E.g. you did something wrong. Or everything works correct and you expect something wrong. Or you are using myisam on one and innodb on the other server. I am not even sure how the two servers are related. A transaction can only have an effect if you open two connections to the same server and I don't see anything related to this yet. So please: describe step by step what you did.

Comment: @Solarflare please explain one thing. If I update the table should I use the value before the transaction or the one that I have updated during transaction. that's all the confusion in transaction.

Comment: Very simplified: Inside a transaction, it does not matter if you started the transaction or not (apart from not being able to rollback later). It only affects what others can see (if they exist). You can think of a transaction as the database looking like you are the only one that is using it: you see all changes done in your transaction, and no changes done by others. How much changes done by others you can see will actually depend on the isolation level, but that's beyond the scope of this comment (and there is a lot of documentation about it). Not sure if that answers your problem though.